# Providing custom files for git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

My project uses [Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) as a submodule in `/machine`.

VVV offers the possibility to configure it through custom files. My custom files are:

```
machine/
├── Customfile
├── config
│   └── nginx-config
│       └── sites
│           └── mysite.conf
└── www
    └── mysite
        ├── vvv-hosts
        ├── vvv-init.sh
        └── wp-cli.yml
```

These paths are all ignored in VVV's `.gitignore` file.

What's a good way of providing these files in my project so that they sit in the same directory as vvv when the whole project is recursively cloned? *Hopefully without having to make a fork that tracks these files*.

Simply adding the submodule with these files present has the following result:

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV.git machine/
'machine' already exists and is not a valid git repo
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps using symlinks would work?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831877/git-include-files-from-other-repositories/22179091#22179091

Comment: Just to clarify, all these files in the `machine` subdirectory are your own files, right?  And you'd like to somehow clone and get a copy of the VVV project with your `machine` subdirectory, and all its files, inside it?

Comment: Yes @palimpsestor, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

From `git help submodule`,

> Submodules allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated
>          subdirectory of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

Your invocation of `git submodule add` is complaining because you are trying to embed the foreign VVV repository in the subdirectory `machine`, which, as the message said, already exists and is not a valid git repo.

To get your desired directory structure, with `machine` as a subdirectory of the VVV directory, you'd have to have your repo as a submodule of theirs, not the other way around.

Given that, I don't see how you could get a single `git clone` to pull both repos and organize them as you'd like.  Next best might be to have your repo pull the VVV repo as a submodule/subdirectory parallel to your `machine` directory and include a script to establish a symlink to `machine` from inside the VVV subdirectory.